# Angular singe-page application routing within a page other than index.html

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have an application that is not a single-page application and different pages are rendered after being sent to the client from an API. After I navigate to a page, say `example.html`, with this method, is it possible to use a `<div ng-view>` in `example.html` and route between different views within `example.html` with `$routeprovider`. Or does the Angular routing have to happen within `index.html`?

How would I do so? What would the directory structure need to be?

Thanks!

Comment: where is your bootstrap? (ng-app or manual bootstrap)

Comment: Did you try it? No firm rule that angular has to be in index file